# Error in DB connection for Ports with Psycopg2 and Python

Tags: python-2.7, port, psycopg2, heroku-postgres

Pretty new to development - I am seeing the following error when I deploying my .py script.  I have referenced my creds as follows:

reference:

```
# Postgresql initialization
connection = psycopg2.connect(
    host= "Host",
    dbname= "Database",
    port= "Port",
    user= "User",
    password= "Password")
```

The error message:

```
error:
    2018-09-16T18:19:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.501301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.521042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.408361+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.408378+00:00 app[web.1]:   """)
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409434+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409439+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "app.py", line 24, in <module>
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409629+00:00 app[web.1]:     password= "Password")
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409631+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409824+00:00 app[web.1]:     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409851+00:00 app[web.1]: psycopg2.OperationalError: invalid port number: "Port"
    2018-09-16T18:19:46.409855+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Can anyone help?  Why is my port throwing issue?

Comment: Is that the actual code you are using? Did you just copy and paste it? "Port" is not a valid port number.

Comment: i assumed we would reference everything in variables...originally I had them all written as Port= "process.env.Port"      Is that not correct?  I was trying to limit Key type items from being hard coded in GIT

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code you're passing strings that have no bearing on establishing a connection. Instead, you should be reading the url, password, port, etc out of the environment. In fact, Heroku puts all of these together into a connection string on your behalf. Try this ([heroku documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-python)):

```python
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']

conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
```